# why not working properly Multiple chronometer Count Up Timer in my recycler view?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have several count-up timers in my Android app (use the Chronometer class) and I want these timers to work independently, but when I start the first-timer, the second-timer works from the continuation of this first-timer.
.

- I use Toggle-button for the start and stop the timer.
- below code is for adapter class .

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{

```
Context context;
ArrayList<Item> listItem;
MyDatabase db ;
private int a = 0 ;
private boolean  pause , running;
private long pauseOffset;



public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> listItem) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listItem = listItem;
    db = new MyDatabase(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_item, parent, false));
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)  {
   final Item item = listItem.get(position);
    holder.toggelButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        if (isChecked) {



                holder.chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset );
                holder.chronometer.start();



        } else {
                holder.chronometer.stop();
                pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - holder.chronometer.getBase();
        }
    });
    holder.btn_reset.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        holder.chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        holder.chronometer.stop();
        pauseOffset = 0 ;
    });
    holder.btn_menu.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_dialog_menu);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        Button delete , calender ;
         delete = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
         calender = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_calender);

         delete.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
             db.deleteItem(item.getId());
             listItem.remove(position);
             notifyItemRemoved(position);
             notifyItemRangeChanged(position , listItem.size());
             dialog.cancel();
             db.close();
         });
         dialog.show();


    });
    holder.circleImageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    holder.txt_name.setText(item.getImageName());
    holder.btn_save.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if((running = true) || (pause=true)){
            long Milliseconds= SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - holder.chronometer.getBase();

            String time = Long.toString(Milliseconds);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d");
            String date = sdf.format(new Date());

            Item item1 = new Item();
            item1.time = time;
            item1.date = date;
            String name = item.getImageName();
            try {
                db.store_time_date(time ,date ,name );
                Toast.makeText(context, "data add to data base", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }


    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return  listItem == null ? 0 : listItem.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    Chronometer chronometer;
    ToggleButton toggelButton;
    CircleImageView circleImageView;
    Button btn_calender, btn_menu, btn_save ,btn_reset;
    TextView txt_name;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        chronometer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
        toggelButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btn_menu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
        btn_save  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        btn_reset = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reset);
    }
}
```

}